# Why am I getting a "Permission denied error" while trying to read a cell value using openpyxl python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Error:

self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\gst_filer\invoice_data\jan\~$Jan05 Miracle gurukrupa.xlsx'

Code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=os.path.abspath(file), read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
cell_val = ws.cell(row=6,column=2)
print(cell_val)
```

Comment: some file will not be accessible if it is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to the answer with `with statement` (which is very good):

```py
elf.fp = io.open(file, filemode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'D:\gst_filer\invoice_data\jan\~$Jan05 Miracle gurukrupa.xlsx'
```

make sure that your file is not `used by another process`, such as `excel app` or another `program that reads .xlsx`

Comment: Both the answers are useful but the real reason was that the program was stored in 'D:' which is an external removable drive and hence the program was not having the administrative privileges to access the excel file. However after saving the file at another location 'C:' the program works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `with` statement and there's no `close()` statement so if this is not the first time you're running the code, it's likely that you haven't closed the file properly and it is still sitting in the memory and prevents access.

Try closing Python and re-starting and also modify your code:

```
with openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=os.path.abspath(file), read_only=True) as wb:
    ws = wb.active
    cell_val = ws.cell(row=6,column=2)
    print(cell_val)
```

And try use context manager whenever you are reading/writing data from/to file.

Comment: openpyxl workbooks are not context managers.

Comment: @CharlieClark, my bad, I thought they were.